# Can't upload image in django use MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL

Tags: python, django, django-models

hello i want to make upload image in admin django but when i use media_root and media url image can not upload. this is model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category        = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    userprofile     = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price           = models.IntegerField()
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    description     = models.TextField()
    created_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title;
```

setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT  = '/static/images/upload/'
MEDIA_URL   = '/upload/'
```

view.py

```
def home(request):
    posts = Product.objects.filter(created_date__isnull=False)
    return render(request, 'kerajinan/product_list.html', {
        'posts'         : posts,
        'categories'    : Category.objects.all(),
    })
```

and this is tamplate product.html

```
<img src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="" />
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MEDIA_ROOT` is an **absolute** path to the uploaded images so you should change the setting to something like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/upload')
```

The second problem is in the image field definition.  `upload_to` argument is a path [**relative**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) to the `MEDIA_ROOT`/`MEDIA_URL`.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product')
```

And it is better to add some `strftime()` formatting to reduce the number of files in the single directory:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: thanks its work, but how to show image with tag img like this <img src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="" /> image cannot loaded. how?

Comment: Here is the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development